# JavaScript Array to PHP on another page

Tags: php, javascript, json, post

I am trying to pass two arrays that I have created in JavaScript to another php page. I have researched this and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have been following many forums and tutorials but I can't seem to get mine to work. 
I have a form which you can add additional lines which is why I have arrays. When the user presses submit on "process.php," this function is called:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var accosArray = new Array();
    accomp = $("#TextBoxDiv1 textarea[name=sacco]").val();
    accosArray.push(accomp);
    alert(accosArray[0]);
    for (var i = 2; i < counter; i++) {
        accomp = $("#TextBoxDiv1" + i + " textarea[name=sacco]").val();
        accosArray.push(accomp);
        alert(accosArray[i - 1]);
    }
    var tasksArray = new Array();
    taskSelect = $("#TextBoxDiv1 select[name=lstDropDown_A]").val();
    if (taskSelect == "") {
        //If user entered a task
        taskOther = $("#TextBoxDiv1 input[name=textboxoption_A]").val();
        tasksArray.push(taskOther);
        alert(tasksArray[0]);
    } else {
        tasksArray.push(taskSelect);
        alert(tasksArray[0]);
    }
    for (var i = 2; i < counter; i++) {
        taskSelect = $("#TextBoxDiv1" + i + " select[name=lstDropDown_A]").val();
        if (taskSelect == "") {
            //If user entered a task
            taskOther = $("#TextBoxDiv1" + i + " input[name=textboxoption_A]").val();
            tasksArray.push(taskOther);
            alert(tasksArray[i - 1]);
        } else {
            tasksArray.push(taskSelect);
            alert(tasksArray[i - 1]);
        }
    }
    $.post('127.0.0.1/Working Files/Best Files/In Progress/status.php';, {
        task: tasksArray
    }, function(result) {
        alert(result[0]);
    }, 'json');
});
```

This puts the user inputs into the arrays and then I try to use the $.post method at the end in order to be able to pass the arrays to the next page but I am not sure if the syntax is correct.

Then it is passed to the next file, "status.php," which at the beginning states:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $task=$_POST['task'];
 echo json_encode($task);
?>
```

The echo shows as "null."

Please let me know what I am doing wrong!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your `$.post` line contains a misplaced semicolon.

Comment: removed now. still echos "null"

Comment: There are several steps involved, the bug could be in any of them. I personally would use Firebug or a similar tool to look at the actual request and response data that is being exchanged. And use `console.log` instead of `alert()`, because it can display more than just plain strings.

Comment: Do an echo of `$_POST['task']`. And at  most it will be `json_decode($task)` not encode.

Comment: So I am using firebug and I found where the bug is but I don't understand it. This is what is says: POST .../status.php and jquery (line 8240). The line from jquery says: `xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );` Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a rogue semicolon at the very least:

```
$.post('127.0.0.1/Working Files/Best Files/In Progress/status.php';
```

Remove that semicolon for starters...

Comment: removed the semicolon. still null. btw I am very new to javascript so sorry for my messy code.

Comment: You'll also need to put quotes around your JSON parameter: "task" : tasksArray